# Why are my pop-up windows opening in a new tab on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, window, tabs, popups

I am working on a feature for a web app on my local server. The feature opens a pop-up window when you click on a button and shows some information. It has been working completely fine up until this morning and now when I click the button (or any other pop-up buttons) it opens in a new tab? Are there any settings I can change to return it to a pop-up? I am using Google Chrome and have changed nothing to my code since it was working fine yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Turn pop-ups on or off

- On your computer, open Chrome.
- At the top right, click More. Settings.
- At the bottom, click Advanced.
- Under 'Privacy and security', click Site settings.
- Click Pop-ups and redirects.
- At the top, turn the setting to Allowed or Blocked.